# How to move a DIV in the DOM w a flash player, while not causing the flash player to refresh

Tags: jquery, html, flash

I have something like this:

```
<div id="doc">

  <div id="main">
  </div>

  <div id="rail">
    <div id="video">
      <object>....</object>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

If I use:

```
$('#video').appendTo('#doc');
```

The flash refreshes. Is there a way to move the div and not cause flash to refresh?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried .detach? I am pretty confident any call that creates a clone will reset the flash -- the dom has no way of knowing the state of the flash object so it can reinstate it.

Answer (score 0):

Per @Mark Robbins' comment, changing the actual hierarchical position of the flash container div is the problem here. If the rest of your code permits it, you could create an absolutely positioned div for your flash `<object>` and move from one place to another within your layout, instead of removing it & adding it to the dom with `.appendTo()`.

Not an ideal solution as you'd probably need to modify your layout, but it would let you move the div w/o the Flash refreshing. :\